# Decimal number, to_char, and Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out a format spec of to_char() that would give me the following result.

```
to_char(0.1, '[FORMAT_SPEC]')
```

gives 0.1 and:

```
to_char(1, '[FORMAT_SPEC]')
```

gives 1.

I've tried the following solutions:

```
to_char(0.1)
```

gives '.1'.

```
to_char(0.1, 'FM0.099')
```

gives 0.1, which is okay, however:

```
to_char(1, 'FM0.099')
```

gives 1.0, which is not okay.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precision returned needs to be consistent, so the only alternative is to use [DECODE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) or [CASE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) statements to conditionally return what you need:

```
CASE 
  WHEN INSTR(TO_CHAR(t.col), '.') = 0 THEN TO_CHAR(t.col)
  ELSE TO_CHAR(t.col, 'FM0.099')
END
```

The example isn't great - it's not clear if your data will have values like `1.000` or values above one/etc.

EDIT Michael-O (2013-06-25): For those who need it idiot-proof, you may try:

```
case
  when instr(to_char(<col>), (select to_char(0, 'FMD') from dual))  = 0
    then to_char(<col>) 
  else to_char(<col>, 'FM999990D999')
end
```

It automatically observes the decimal separator. Adapt the the secodn format modal to your number size.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Oracle for screwing up formatting.

Comment: `(select to_char(0,'FMD') from dual)` can be simplified down to `to_char(0,'FMD')` can be simplified down to `'.'`.

Answer (score 2):

I just use this:

```
TRIM('.' FROM TO_CHAR(x, 'FM99990.999'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't happen to have an Oracle instance handy to test this in, but I'd think that

```
TO_CHAR(1, 'FM0.999')
```

oughta do it.

Comment: That will give "0.1" and "1." for the values.

Comment: OK, then  RTRIM(TO_CHAR(1, 'FM0.999'), '.')

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what range of values you will be expecting but you could case out values < 1 versus those >= 1.  Otherwise either the trailing 0 or the decimal is going to get in your way:

```
select val,
       case when val < 1 then to_char(val, 'FM99990.9')
            else to_char(val, 'FM99999')
       end fmt
  from (select 0.1 val from dual union all
        select 1 from dual
       )
/

       VAL FMT
---------- --------
        .1 0.1
         1 1
```