# Oracle TO_CHAR Format Mask for displaying both integral numbers and floating point numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, number-formatting

I'm trying to find the correct Oracle format mask to display numbers on an Apex page in a report in a certain way.
Most of the times these numbers are integers but sometimes these numbers can be floating point numbers.
Let's say I have the following three queries:

Query 1

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1, '<Format Mask>', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.1, '<Format Mask>', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;
```

Query 3

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.01, '<Format Mask>', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;
```

Now I want to use one single format mask which will give me the following results:

Result 1

```
1
```

Result 2

```
0,1
```

Result 3

```
0,01
```

Can anyone provide me with the correct format mask to achieve this?
I've tried a format mask like **FM990D999** but it leaves me with a comma trailing the 1 in Query 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal number, to\_char, and Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033756/decimal-number-to-char-and-oracle)

Comment: @Ben Yes, the question is very similar, I had not found that one yet. However, the answer given is not very satisfactory for my situation since I can only specify the format mask in Apex. Otherwise I would have to generate the string in an earlier stage which breaks sorting behaviour in the Apex report.

Comment: @BartvanderDrift - you can't `trim` the string you get with your format mask?

Comment: Are these numbers all in the same column in the report or are they different columns? Is this a classic or interactive report?

Comment: @Alex - Alas, I cannot. Apex only allows me to specify a format mask. Any additional string manipulation would have to take place in the Query stage, breaking the sorting behaviour of the report.

Comment: @Tom - I have multiple reports with multiple columns in which this behaviour shows. They are interactive reports.

Comment: Yes, it is somewhat of a limitation of Apex. You specify a query which is shown in the report. This query will return a number such that Apex can offer functionality such as sorting and searching above or below a certain value. You can also specify the format mask which should be used to display the number on the screen. Changing the column type to VARCHAR2 instead of NUMBER will change the sorting, for example, to alphabetical, which is very confusing to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to alter your column value in the query while still retaining (some) of the functionality in the report(s). However, having multiple such columns and multiple report you might find there is a lot of overhead for little gain.
Look at this post on the OTN forums: [order by date in IR](https://community.oracle.com/message/11306530#11306530)
The issue is much the same: the data in the column represents a date but is actually not a date. This post contains a solution to use in apex < 4.2.
From 4.2 onwards you have a better option called the HTML expression.
Again, linked from OTN: [Re: Report formatting/sorting issue](https://community.oracle.com/message/4177275#4177275)

Quoted from linked post, user fac586

> Include both variance and abs(variance) in the query:
>
> ```
> SELECT
>         region,
>         estimate,
>         actual,
>         (estimate - actual) AS variance,
>         ABS(estimate - actual) AS abs_variance,
>         (CASE 
>           WHEN (estimate - actual)>=0 THEN 'green'
>           WHEN (estimate - actual)<0 THEN 'red'
>           ELSE NULL
>         END) AS variance_color
> from
>         expenses
> ```
>
> And the HTML Expression for the "variance" column is:
>
> ```
> <span style="color: #VARIANCE_COLOR#; font-weight: bold;">#ABS_VARIANCE#</span>
> ```
>
> Hide the `#VARIANCE_COLOR#` and `#ABS_VARIANCE#` columns.
>
> `#ABS_VARIANCE#` is the value shown in the column, but the sort is
>   performed in the underlying SQL using the original variance value.

This is much like Alex suggested but is a bit more work: formatting in the source, adding an html expression, hiding the other column.
I suppose it depends on how far you want to drive it. Why not just apply the format to the column through its attributes?
Also be aware it is possible to use string substitution syntax in those fields. You could have a couple application items containing format masks, and then reference the correct mask in the format mask field.
Eg:
Application item `AI_FORMAT_MASK1` has a value `FM9990D00`.
In the format mask field you can then use `&AI_FORMAT_MASK1.`

Comment: Tom, I like your solution using two different columns. I'm going to try this. I'm using an HTML expression anyway to concatenate a unit to the field.